# Can you get into Mario RPG's Debug Room on the Wii Virtual Console?

Tags: virtual-console, super-mario-rpg

I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XwAT8LTkCY) which showed Mario RPG's debug room and thought I'd go try it out. Either I've got the wrong idea about what triggers the debug room or it doesn't work for the Wii.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's triggered by a value at a specific memory address; these things usually are. Without the equivalent of a Game Genie/Action Replay, there would no way to access it.

Comment: The video made it look like this was triggered by meeting a conditional. I was thinking Mario's name = "Red" and then just continue to Bowser's Keep. Many Squaresoft games had debug rooms that players could reach through normal gameplay but I don't have an SNES anymore to test that theory out >_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the Wii Virtual Console games are basically exactly the same as the originals (with all the glitches), unfortunately there is no way to replicate the cheats necessary to enter the "Debug Room", so the Debug Room can NOT be accessed.